# When use Selenium exception turns out with no attribute 'urlopen'

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, webdriver, urllib

Right now I have the test code from the Selenium library. I am trying to test if it's gonna work and then do my own edits on it. However, it goes wrong on the 'import' part. I have all libraries installed already. Please help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# go to the google home page
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

# the page is ajaxy so the title is originally this:
print driver.title

# find the element that's name attribute is q (the google search box)
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("q")

# type in the search
inputElement.send_keys("cheese!")

# submit the form (although google automatically searches now without submitting)
inputElement.submit()

try:
    # we have to wait for the page to refresh, the last thing that seems to be updated is the title
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("cheese!"))

    # You should see "cheese! - Google Search"
    print driver.title

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Exception is as followed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Edison/Desktop/supreme/supTest.py", line 12, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver`enter code here`
  File "/Users/Edison/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "/Users/Edison/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .extension_connection import ExtensionConnection
  File "/Users/Edison/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 24, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import RemoteConnection
  File "/Users/Edison/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib2 as url_request
  File "/Users/Edison/Desktop/supreme/urllib2.py", line 2, in <module>
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.baidu.com/')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: I tried the same code with `Python-3.5, Selenium-3.0.1, Chrome-56, Chromedriver-` and working fine. Please specify the environment details. It seems to be a compatibility issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have a script named `urllib2.py` in the working directory. When Selenium looked up `urllib2`, it found that script of yours, which doesn't have a `urlopen` attribute. Rename that script with a unique identifier, like `my_url_project.py`.